# Finding the shortest path in a colored graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

The problem I am trying to solve is:

Given a graph where each edge is colored in either red or blue:

a) Give an algorithm that produces the path that between two vertices (s,t) that goes over a minimal amount of red edges.

b) Give an algorithm that produces the path that between two vertices (s,t) that goes over a minimal amount of blue edges, out of all the paths that go from s to t that pass through a minimal amount of red edges.

So far:
For a) I can use a modified BFS algorithm. When looking at a vertex, v, put all the vertices that are connected by a blue edge to v first in the queue, and then add the rest to the end of the queue. Thus, the first time the algorithm will encounter t will be the path in question.

How do I prove correctness of this algorithm? It seems very greedy. How do I expand this to answer b)?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What happens when the "blue" path out of s has two red paths between that node and t, if the first "red" path out of s has nothing but "blue" paths of nodes to reach t?  (Counter example to your strategy)

Comment: Have you considered weighting the graph? In the case of A, you could assign a weight of 0 to the blue edges, and a weight of 1 to the red edges, then find the path with the least cost. Then for B, just reverse the weighting.

Comment: @Joel: Your suggestion for b) doesn't work because we still primarily want to minimize red edges. Blue edges are just used as the tie breaker

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: OPs algorithm would still find the correct path. You can just verify that on paper

Comment: @NiklasB. ah, you're absolutely right, I misread what was being asked in B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important details about your algorithm that you need to keep in mind:

1. Nodes can be added to the queue multiple times in your scenario. You are only allowed to explore them once, though. You can enforce that by maintaining a boolean flag per node that tells you whether you have already explored a node.
2. You can only stop the algorithm as soon as you take `t` *out of the queue*, not as soon as you put it in.

If you do it this way (and your question doesn't indicate you don't), your algorithm is indeed correct.

> How do I prove correctness of this algorithm?

If you assign edge weight `1` to red edges and edge weight `0` to blue edges, the problem reduces to find the shortest path in the transformed graph. Let's apply Dijkstra to this problem. I will show that your algorithm in fact implements Dijkstra, which proves its correctness.

We can show that we only ever have nodes of two different distances in the priority queue: If `m` is the minimum distance of a node in the priority queue, then we can't have a node of distance `m + 2` in the queue, because that would mean that we must already have explored a node with distance `m + 1`, which is impossible because we explore nodes in order of increasing distance.

Your modified BFS in fact implements the Dijkstra algorithm using a double-ended queue as the 2-value priority queue: If `Q` is your queue, then there is an index `i`, such that `Q[1..i]` contains only nodes of distance `m` and `Q[i+1..]` contains only nodes of distance `m + 1`.

> How do I expand this to answer b)?

You can extend the concept by maintaining a 4-value priority queue, for example implemented as two double-ended queue. One queue will hold nodes of distance `m` red edges, the other will hold nodes of distance `m + 1` red edges. Both are ordered by increasing number of blue edges (there will also only be two different distance values in each of these).

Answer (score 0):

[[The algorithm mentioned is correct if you put nodes adjacent to blue edges in front of queue instead of end of the queue as discussed in comment.]]

For problem (B) just discard the edges which are not in original shortest path(which uses minimum red edges). Its easy to find if a edge u-v is in shortest path. u-v is in shortest path if distance[source][u]+cost[u][v]+distance[v][destination]=distance[source][destination]. After discarding extra edges rest of the task is easy.

Comment: OPs algorithm is in fact correct. It finds the shortest path on the right.

Comment: @ Niklas B: He will go from source to "a" and "c". than he will process "a" and go to "b" and than from "c" to "d". than he will to b to destination and terminate the algorithm. source-a-b-destination is clearly not optimal.

Comment: No. He will never go to `b` because it is added to the end of the queue (after `c`), while `d` is added to the front of the queue after `c` is explored

Comment: So perhaps I need to store something along the lines of a "current shortest path" and update it every time I reach t for the algorithm to be correct? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you add a node in front of the queue in bfs? I don't think so, you are not traversing level bu level than. I think he meant he will process blue edges first, than red edges.

Comment: @Shafaet: Yes you can, the order is irrelevant. Quote from the question: "put all the vertices that are connected by a blue edge to v first in the queue, and then add the rest to the end of the queue" which is valid and yields a correct algorithm

Comment: I assumed OP meant he will process blue edges "first" and than red ones and assumed he will put every thing in end of the queue. If he meant what you said still there is a problem. Consider the graph: S-a(blue), S-b(blue),a-D(Red),b-D(Blue). First he will put a,b in queue. Than how can he decide whether to process a or b first? If he takes a first than he will go to a-D and terminate which is not optimal.

Comment: Shafaet: I think the formulation "add the rest to the end of the queue" is pretty unambiguous. You have to terminate the algorithm only if you take the target (D in this case) out of the queue. At that point you know that the distance is `1`, independent of the order in which you process a and b. There's a certain subtlety though, which I have overlooked at first: A node can be added to the queue twice, but you're only allowed to process a node once.

Comment: @ Niklas B: You are right, that does work. I misunderstood the question i guess, edited my original answer.